# Is there any solution to scrape using Web Scraper(crome extension) when page list is not given?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping

Is there any solution to scrape using Web Scraper(crome extension) when the page list is not given (such as [1]-[2]-[3]---[2000]). Instead here [1]-[next][last] is given. How can I select the next button to complete pagination?

My page link is here:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have actually tried so far, and explain where the actual problem lies?

Comment: pagination problem, I gave the page pattern in my question. During pagination using chrome extension we select 1,2,3 then all pages are automatically selected. But when the pattern is: like the given link I could not select it.